# Order sublist by creation date

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a list of products that each contain another list of products. I want to order these lists by a propriety called `CreationDate`. I managed to order the main list but I can´t seem to order the sublists without using a for each. For now I have this:

```
products = products
 .Where(product => product.ProductAlternatives
 .Any(productAlt => (productAlt.ProductAlternativeStatusId == Util.ProductStatus.ACTIVE) 
   || (productAlt.ProductAlternativeStatusId == Util.ProductStatus.TRANSFERRED) 
   || (productAlt.ProductAlternativeStatusId == Util.ProductStatus.DELETED)))
.OrderBy(y => y.CreationDate); //order the products by creation date
```

Order the alternative products by creation date:

```
foreach (var product in products) { 
    product.ProductAlternatives = product.ProductAlternatives
                                         .OrderBy(x => x.CreationDate)
                                         .ToList();
}
```

Is there any better way?
Thanks!

**EDIT**: In the question pointed out to as duplicate, the solution was

```
parents = (from p in parents
       orderby p.Name
       select new Parent
       {
           Name = p.Name,
           Children = p.Children.OrderBy(c => c.Name).ToList()
       }
      ).ToList();
```

My question is, what if Parent has many proprieties, should all of them be appointed manually in `select new Parent`?

Comment: May be .GroupBy is your friend...

Comment: you could do something like  .Select(pp => new product { ProductAlternatives = pp.ProductAlternatives.OrderBy(x => x.CreationDate) }) // ???

Comment: would this work if Product has many other proprieties?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!